# Evaluate the volume of $A_r=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2; x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2zr \}$

Tags: multiple-integral

> Evaluate the volume of
>   $$A_r=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2;\, x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2zr \}.$$

I use spherical coordinates so i found $\theta \in [0,\pi], \phi \in [0,2\pi]$ but for $\rho $ i have two choise: $ \rho \le r$ or $\rho \le 2r \cos \theta$. Have I to divide the range of $\theta$ ?

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_{0}^{r} {\rho}^2 \sin \theta\dots+\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2r\cos \theta}....?$$

Comment: In the second integral the range of $\theta$ is from $\pi/3$ to $\pi/2$ (not $\pi$). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The inequality $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2zr$ can be written as
$$x^2+y^2+(z-r)^2\leq r^2.$$ Therefore $A_r$ is the intersection of two balls of radius $r$: one is centered at $(0,0,0)$ and the other at $(0,0,r)$.

In spherical coordinates  you need to split the evaluation into two parts:
$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_{0}^{r} {\rho}^2 \sin \theta  d\rho d\theta d\phi
+\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2r\cos \theta}{\rho}^2 \sin \theta d\rho d\theta d\phi.$$
Note that in your formula, in the second integral, the range of $\theta$ is from $\pi/3$ to $\pi/2$ (not $\pi$).

We may also use cylindrical coordinates:
$$V=\int_{\rho=0}^{\sqrt{3}r/2}\left(
\int_{z=r-\sqrt{r^2-\rho^2}}^{z=\sqrt{r^2-\rho^2}}\left(\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}d\theta\right) dz\right)\rho d\rho.$$

Comment: The result is $(5/12) \pi r^3$?

Comment: @Wauzl Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: @GiuliaB. Yes, the result is correct!! Did you try also the cylindrical coordinates? Any further doubt?

Comment: if I want calculate $\int_{A_r} z^2 dx dy dz $ do I use cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @GiuliaB. You can use both cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

Comment: The result is $(\pi/6) r^4$?

Comment: I calculate $(5/48) \pi r^5$.Is it right?

Comment: @GiuliaB. My result is different...

Comment: What do you have?

Comment: The integrale is the same  of V but i integrate the function$\rho^4 (\cos\theta)^2 (\sin\theta) $ in both integrals

Comment: Fine. So, edit your question by adding the new integral $\int_{A_r} z^2 dx dy dz$ and write a couple of steps of your evaluation.

Comment: I have the sum of two  integrals: the result of first is $ (7/60)\pi r^5$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69155/discussion-between-robert-z-and-giulia-b).